# Show that $\int _0^1\frac{\ln \left(1+\left(\frac{1-t}{1+t}\right)^2\right)}{t\left(\ln t\right)^2}dt=\ln 2$

Tags: integration

According to [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%5Bln(1%2B((1-x)%2F(1%2Bx))%5E2)%2F(x(ln(x))%5E2)%5D) the integral 
$$\int _0^1\frac{\ln \left(1+\left(\frac{1-t}{1+t}\right)^2\right)}{t\left(\ln t\right)^2}dt$$
is shown to have a decimal expansion exactly identical to $\ln 2$.

How can we prove they are equal?

This integral came about as a result of integrating by parts

$$\int_0^x\frac{\arctan t}{\ln \left(t\right)\left(1+t\right)^2}dt$$

with

$u=\frac{1}{\ln t}$

$dv=\frac{\arctan t}{\left(1+t\right)^2}dt$

$du=-\frac{1}{t\ln^2 t}dt$

$v=\frac{1}{4}\ln \left(2\right)-\frac{1}{4}\ln \left(1+\left(\frac{1-t}{1+t}\right)^2\right)-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1-t}{1+t}\right)\arctan \left(t\right)$

Comment: Ok, this seems like as good a time as any to ask, "where the heck did you get this?"

Comment: I responded to your question @Chris

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The given integral equals
$$\begin{eqnarray*} I &=& \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log(2)+\log(1+t^2)-2\log(1+t)}{t\log^2t}\,dt\\&\stackrel{t\mapsto e^{-x}}{=}&\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\log(2)+\log(1+e^{-2x})-2\log(1+e^{-x})}{x^2}\,dx\\&\stackrel{\text{IBP}}{=}&2\int_{0}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{1}{e^x+1}-\frac{1}{e^{2x}+1}\right)\frac{dx}{x} \tag{1}\end{eqnarray*}$$
and the claim simply follows by recalling [Frullani's theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrullanisIntegral.html).
As an alternative, 
$$\mathcal{L}\left(\frac{1}{e^x+1}\right) = \frac{1}{2}\left(H_{\frac{s}{2}}-H_{\frac{s-1}{2}}\right)\tag{2}$$
[leads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Evaluating_integrals_over_the_positive_real_axis) to

$$ I = 2\lim_{s\to +\infty}\log\left(\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{s+2}{4}\right)\,\Gamma\left(\frac{s+2}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{s+4}{4}\right)\,\Gamma\left(\frac{s+1}{2}\right)}\right) = \color{red}{\log 2}\tag{3}$$
by Stirling's inequality.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:**
$$\int\frac{\ln(1+(\dfrac{1-t}{1+t})^2)}{t(\ln t)^2}=\int\frac{\ln2}{t(\ln t)^2}+\int\frac{\ln(1+t^2)}{t(\ln t)^2}-2\int\frac{\ln(1+t)}{t(\ln t)^2}=\int\frac{\ln2}{t(\ln t)^2}$$

Comment: Can you elaborate on the last equality?

Comment: The second integral will be equal to the third with $t^2=u$.

Comment: I'm making the $u$-substitution in the second integral and while some of the terms are playing nice, in the denominator the $\ln(t)^2$ doesn't seem to go well with your substitution.

Comment: @Chris $(\log(t^2))^2=4\log^2(t)$ and $dt\to 2t\,dt$ upon substitution.

Comment: @MarkViola welp, hold on a sec and I'll try that!

Comment: Actually, I'm a little concerned here. Clearly $\frac{d}{dt} [\frac{-1}{\ln(t)}] = \frac{1}{t\ln(t)^2}$, but then when you go to evaluate the integral (from $0$ to $1$) I find that the value is $+\infty$. This doesn't correspond to what the OP had.

Comment: I have the same problem as Chris since $\int\frac{dt}{t(\ln t)^2}=-\frac 1 {\log(t)}$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici the "canceled" integrals also diverge (at $t=1$), one has to be really careful about the split here...

Comment: @tired this is the primary reason I wanted the OP to clarify his full solution.

Comment: the upvotes are a big miracle...

Comment: If the site allowed me to remove my upvote from this post, to be very frank, I would do so. I'm bothered by the lack of detail in how you deal with the cancellation of divergent integrals, and why your answer apparently has a numerical discrepancy with the OP's calculation.

Comment: @Chris you should be able to remove your upvote if you really want

Comment: @tired System tells me I'm locked in unless the post is edited. I wasn't trying to be dramatic, but I don't expect the post will be edited anytime soon.

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't work (although it's nice to see "that the second integral will be equal to the third"). Correction factors are necessary to make sense on it. As *tired* said: *the upvotes are a big miracle* ...

Answer (score 1):

Using $\enspace\displaystyle\zeta(0)=-\frac{1}{2}\enspace$ and $\enspace\displaystyle\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{2^h-1}{h}=\ln 2$

and $\enspace\displaystyle\int _0^\infty\frac{x^{h-1}}{e^{ax}+1}dx=\frac{2^{h-1}-1}{2^{h-1}a^h}\zeta(h)\Gamma(h)\enspace$ for $\enspace h,a>0\enspace$

and $\enspace\displaystyle t:=e^{-x}\enspace$ we get:

$\displaystyle\int _0^1\frac{\ln \left(1+\left(\frac{1-t}{1+t}\right)^2\right)}{t\left(\ln t\right)^2}dt=\int _0^\infty\frac{\ln 2+\ln(1+e^{-2x})-2\ln(1+e^{-x})}{x^2}dx$

$\displaystyle=2\int _0^\infty (\frac{1}{e^{2x}+1}-\frac{1}{e^{x}+1}) \frac{dx}{x}=2\lim\limits_{h\to 0} \int _0^\infty (\frac{x^{h-1}}{e^{2x}+1}-\frac{x^{h-1}}{e^{x}+1})dx$

$\displaystyle=2\lim\limits_{h\to 0} \zeta(h)\Gamma(h+1)\frac{2^{h-1}-1}{2^{2h-1}}\frac{2^h-1}{h}=2(-\frac{1}{2}\frac{2^{-1}-1}{2^{-1}}\ln 2)=\ln 2$